# How to make a press proof with crop marks and color bars?

Tags: crop, proofreading

A standard proof for press needs crop marks and color bars as below

[image]

With the package `crop`, the crop marks can be easily added.

But how about the color bar ?

Is there a way or a package to make it ?

An example is

```
\documentclass[b5paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[cross,a4,center,info,axes]{crop}

\title{Test}
\author{User}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Fox}
The quick brown fox jumps over a lazy dog.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This uses Gonzalo Medina's `background` package and places a plain color table on every page, shifted to 'right' position.

```
\documentclass[b5paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\usepackage[cross,a4,center,info,axes]{crop}

\usepackage{background}



\newcommand{\colorbar}{%
{%
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}%
  \abovedisplayskip=0pt%
  \belowdisplayskip=0pt%
  \begin{tabular}{*{4}{@{}p{0.4cm}@{}}}
    \cellcolor{cyan} & \cellcolor{magenta} & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{black} \tabularnewline
  \end{tabular}%
}%
}


\backgroundsetup{opacity=1,angle=0,scale=1,placement=top,vshift=0.6cm,hshift=6cm,contents={\colorbar}}


\title{Test}
\author{User}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Fox}

The quick brown fox jumps over a lazy dog.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another approach but still taking [@Christian Hupfer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/31729/christian-hupfer)’s `\colorbar`: In case you already have defined some text for `background` you can insert `\colorbar` directly into the `crop`-settings:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[table,cmyk]{xcolor}
\usepackage{background,hyperref}

\newcommand{\colorbar}{%
{%
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{.5}%
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}%
  \abovedisplayskip=0pt%
  \belowdisplayskip=0pt%
  \begin{tabular}{*{4}{@{}p{1cm}@{}}}
    \cellcolor{cyan} & \cellcolor{magenta} & \cellcolor{yellow} & \cellcolor{black} \tabularnewline
  \end{tabular}%
}%
}

\usepackage[
  cam,
  center,
  color=black!50,
  font=textsf,
  width=25truecm,
  height=34truecm
]{crop}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\CROP@@info{%
 \global\advance\CROP@index\@ne
 \def\x{\discretionary{}{}{\hbox{\kern.5em---\kern.5em}}}%
 \dimen@4pt
 \ifx\CROP@pagecolor\@empty 
 \else
 \advance\dimen@\CROP@overlap
 \fi 
 \hb@xt@\z@{%
 \hss
 \vbox to\z@{%
 \centering
 \hsize\paperwidth
 \vss
 \normalfont
 \normalsize
 \expandafter\csname\CROP@font\endcsname{%
 \hspace*{3em}Author\hfill\colorbar\quad\the\year/\the\month/\the\day\x
 \CROP@time\x
 page\kern.5em\thepage\x
 \#\the\CROP@index
 \strut\hspace*{3em}~\\\hspace*{3em}\emph{Title}\hfill 
 Prepress by 
 \href{http://your-company.com}{your-company.com}\hspace*{3em}
 }%
\vskip\dimen@ 
 }%
 \hss
 }}
\makeatother



\title{Test}
\author{User}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Fox}
The quick brown fox jumps over a lazy dog.
\end{document}
```

[image]